# Google Sheets: Joining Two Filters to overwrite selection into 1 Dashboard view

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, filter, dashboard

I'm trying to build a workout tracker like shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=1361&v=PaEbZrAtTGk&feature=youtu.be)

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PqHAx06Gm0POzAAKjki5zAWSWwh59Q3bgpu-ZTWTmus/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy of what I have with dummy data.

Current Attempt/what I've tried/want/notes:

I'd like to have one dashboard (Sheet: Dashboard!) instead of two, where both cells B2 or C2 could be drop downs and I'd like to have it so that the most recent selection takes precedence over the other rules. Currently I've managed to merge the filters with some clunky stepwise IF/THEN, but the final false value supersedes the others, instead of resetting the view.

```
=IF(
    AND(B2="",C2=""),                                   //CONDITION
    FILTER(D1S!A1:AA,D1S!B:B=max(D1S!B$5:B1006)),      //TRUE VALUE/VIEW
                                 //Maybe OR() around entire FALSE VALUE?        
    IF(                                              //FALSE VALUE/VIEW
        B2 <>"",                                            //CONDITION
        FILTER(D1S!A1:AA,D1S!B:B=B2)                  //TRUE VALUE/VIEW
                        //AND Change C2 to string 'Exercise'  //DESIRED
        If(                                          //FALSE VALUE/VIEW
            C2<>"",                                         //CONDITION 
            sort(filter(D1S!A:AA,D1S!C:C=C2),2,FALSE) //TRUE VALUE/VIEW
                        //AND Change B2 to string "Date"      //DESIRED
```

As a result, I don't think conditionals are the way to go here- instead I think Filter may be better. I just don't know the simplest way to do so for both.

Desired outcome:

Essentially, If both B2 and C2 are blank, get the most recent date workout filter view, If either is filled, then get that view which was most recently selected and make the other cell "blank"/ altered to a header string (eg "date" or "exercise").

EG:
When you open the dashboard- nothing is filled so you get the most recent data.
Then if you select a date in B2, from the drop down you get that filter (ignoring/making C2 say "exercise". Then, with this view, if you select an exercise, it will 1- blank out the value in B2 and say "date" and then 2 the view will just be the filtered view of the exercises.

I hope I explained that clearly. Please let me know if any further clarifications are needed!

Comment: Your post is marked with tags `excel` and `google-sheets`. I recommend that you remove whichever does not apply to your situation, since these are very different platforms (or state clearly in your post that you are open to a solution in either).

Comment: sorry fixed that. I figured any solution would be able to carry over from one to the other if it were simple enough, which is why I added the tag.

Comment: Solutions between Excel and GS are rarely transferable as written. In addition, the solution you are requesting is not a "simple" one on either platform. Please see my additional comment on player0's post below.

Answer (score 0):

add one row above then paste this into B1:

```
={""; ""; "Date"}
```

next, paste this into C1:

```
={""; ""; "Exercise"}
```

now you can hide row 1 and perhaps change color to reddish and paste this into A3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IF(ISBLANK(D1S!A3:A), D1S!A3:A, ), D1S!B3:AA}, 
 "where 9=9 "&
 IF(B3="Date",," and Col2 = date '"&TEXT(B3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")&
 IF(C3="Exercise",," and Col3 = '"&C3&"'")))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xbP0O95DDMvWdiMKv4BcdozsjXPlXby8VYMHjFjTaT8/copy)

Comment: Sorry, but not exactly what I'm looking for. If I'm understanding your solution correctly, it is just acting an additional filter, whereas the desired outcome is a reset/overwrite.
EG: In your solution, if we select 1/9/22, we will get a filtered view of all exercises performed on 1/9. If I then decide, to see all days I did deadlift, and select deadlift from the drop down, it will further filter on 1/9 and give me an NA as I did no deadlifts on the specified day.

Comment: Instead I'm looking to toggle between dates and exercises. I would like to see all exercises performed on 1/9. Done. Now, I want to see all days I did deadlift, without the manual step of deleting the date and then filtering for deadlift. I would like the most recent selection (deadlift) to essentially overwrite the initial selection (date = 1/9/22). Is that a better explanation? Sorry if I'm unclear

Comment: The solution you are requesting of the volunteer contributors here will require a script if you do not want to take the additional step of clicking the date or exercise criteria cell and hitting "Delete" to clear (which would literally take one second to do). So to save yourself that one second, you are asking volunteers here to spend quite a bit of time (and in the case of player0, quite a bit of *additional* time) on your behalf at no cost to yourself. If there is a specific, critical reason for not being able to take that extra second to clear a cell, I recommend stating that in your post.

Comment: No, not at all. There is no critical reason for not deleting a cell and then reselecting the filter I would like to see. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it simply. If not, I'm more than satisfied with what I have or what @player0 has graciously taken the time to provide. I just came here to learn and see if others could show me a better way to approach a desired end goal. If that doesn't exist, then that's the answer. All it is for me is a matter of convenience/reducing a manual step to a more automated one.

Comment: All solutions take work. In that regard, there is nothing "simple" (i.e., if it were simple, everyone would be able to do it and there would be no need for this forum or others like it.) For someone who writes formulas and scripts, this task may be "relatively simple"—as when a surgeon reports that laparoscopic gallbladder removal is a "simple procedure." But it takes expertise and time nonetheless. I'm really not intending to be unkind here, just realistic. No forum can offer free fully developed custom solutions. That is what is simply unrealistic.